# Python, объединение списков

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача

> В апреле, июне, сентябре и ноябре – 30 дней. В феврале – 28, или же 29 в високосные годы. Високосный год – год, кратный 4. Года, номер которых кратен 100, — не високосные, но при этом года, которые кратны 400, — високосные. Выведите количество дней в каждом месяце с 1900 по 2018 годы.

Как мне соединить числа месяцев с кол-вом дней в них?

```
dataOne=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,30,31,31] #365
dataTwo=[31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,30,31,31] #366
mounth = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
a=1900
b=2018
for i in range (a,b):
    if ((i%4 == 0 and i%100 != 0) or (i%400 == 0)):
        year1 = mounth[i]+dataOne[i]
        print (i, '=', year1)

    else:
        year2 = mounth[i]+ ':'+dataTwo[i]
        print (i, '=', year2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataOne = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,30,31,31] #365
dataTwo = [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,30,31,31] #366
mounth  = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12]

a = 1900
b = 2018

for i in range (a, b):
    if ((i%4 == 0 and i%100 != 0) or (i%400 == 0)):
        year1 = [ "{} : {}".format(n, dataTwo[i])  for i, n in enumerate(mounth)]
        print("{} -> ".format(i), end="")
        print ("{}".format("{}, "*12).format(*year1))
    else:
        year1 = [ "{} : {}".format(n, dataOne[i])  for i, n in enumerate(mounth)]
        print("{} -> ".format(i), end="")
        print ("{}".format("{}, "*12).format(*year1))

1900 -> 1 : 31, 2 : 28, 3 : 31, 4 : 30, 5 : 31, 6 : 30, 7 : 31, 8 : 31, 9 : 30, 10 : 30, 11 : 31, 12 : 31, 
1901 -> 1 : 31, 2 : 28, 3 : 31, 4 : 30, 5 : 31, 6 : 30, 7 : 31, 8 : 31, 9 : 30, 10 : 30, 11 : 31, 12 : 31, 
1902 -> 1 : 31, 2 : 28, 3 : 31, 4 : 30, 5 : 31, 6 : 30, 7 : 31, 8 : 31, 9 : 30, 10 : 30, 11 : 31, 12 : 31, 
1903 -> 1 : 31, 2 : 28, 3 : 31, 4 : 30, 5 : 31, 6 : 30, 7 : 31, 8 : 31, 9 : 30, 10 : 30, 11 : 31, 12 : 31, 
1904 -> 1 : 31, 2 : 29, 3 : 31, 4 : 30, 5 : 31, 6 : 30, 7 : 31, 8 : 31, 9 : 30, 10 : 30, 11 : 31, 12 : 31, 
1905 -> 1 : 31, 2 : 28, 3 : 31, 4 : 30, 5 : 31, 6 : 30, 7 : 31, 8 : 31, 9 : 30, 10 : 30, 11 : 31, 12 : 31, 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Соединение нескольких списков поэлементно делает функция `zip`, попробуйте

```
dataOne=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,30,31,31] #365
dataTwo=[31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,30,31,31] #366
mounth = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
a=1900
b=2018
for i in range (a,b):
    if ((i%4 == 0 and i%100 != 0) or (i%400 == 0)):
        print(i, ' = ', ', '.join(['{} : {}'.format(m,d) for m,d in zip(mounth, dataOne)]))
    else:
        print(i, ' = ', ', '.join(['{} : {}'.format(m,d) for m,d in zip(mounth, dataTwo)]))
# 1999  =  1 : 31, 2 : 29, 3 : 31, 4 : 30, 5 : 31, 6 : 30, 7 : 31, 8 : 31, 9 : 30, 10 : 30, 11 : 31, 12 : 31
```

PS: `range` итерируется по значениям a <=...< b, чтобы охватить 2018 год тоже - `range (1900,2019)`

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно создать словарь

```
dict_md = {'1': []}  # и тд
```

Есть вариант: можно добавлять в список элементы методом extend, однако помните, что он не создает новый объект, а добавляет в объект.

```
n = [2, 3, 4]
dict_md['1'].append(1)  # dict_md --> '1':[1]
dict_md['1'].extend(n)  # dict_md --> '1':[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос. Если вы не можете ответить по существу, оставьте комментарий к вопросу или ответам.